# Integrated network card stops working

Tags: networking

ECS A75F2-M2, A4-5400k. Latest BIOS.

Same problem with this NC. Ubuntu 20.10 -> 21.04 -> 21.10 -> 22.04 - all same.

The NC works and then the internet just stops working.

This helps:

```
$ sudo nmcli networking off

$ sudo nmcli networking on
```

https://1drv.ms/t/s!Av2nuidly48bmPEZD2XWkw9LHWBk2g?e=jujAjX - here is the log. Is there some useful information? The PC is for testing purpose3s only, so I may experiment. Today I put a IP manually, w/o DHCP. Will see, if this helps.

Thanx!

Comment: Look at the network logs: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. You seem to be on the dangerous path to a Well-known Error: Applying a "solution" before diagnosing the problem.

Comment: [link]https://1drv.ms/t/s!Av2nuidly48bmPEZD2XWkw9LHWBk2g?e=jujAjX[/link]

Here is the log. Is there some useful information? The PC is for testing purpose3s only, so I may experiment.

Today I put a IP manually, w/o DHCP. Will see, if this helps.

Tnanx!

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.